# How can I create multiple msi installers for the same script with different parameters using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I want to create many msi installers from one tkinter script with different parameters to distribute it to different customers. I want this, because I have to change the default installation directory and GUID. I am using the latest stable version of the `cx_Freeze` package and `Python 3.7.9`. When I run the `setup()` function inside `setup.py` it creates the first installer without any problem, but at the second iteration I get an error:

```
running install_exe
copying build\exe.win32-3.7\frozen_application_license.txt -> build\bdist.win32\msi
error: could not create 'build\bdist.win32\msi\frozen_application_license.txt': No such file or directory
```

I already tried to remove the `build` dir after every iteration or modify `argv` after every iteration, but that won't work.

Here's a minimal example of the application to run and get an error. I just run `python setup.py` to create the installers:

`setup.py`

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

sys.argv.append("bdist_msi")

programs = {  # name, GUID pairs
    "hello": "{6ae7456f-2761-43a2-8a23-1a3dd284e947}",
    "world": "{494d5953-651d-41c5-a6ef-9156c96987a1}",
}

for program, GUID in programs.items():
    setup(
        name=f"Hello-{program}",
        version="1.0",
        executables=[Executable("hello.py")],
        options={
            "bdist_msi": {
                "initial_target_dir": f"C:\{program}",
                "upgrade_code": GUID,
            },
        },
    )
```

`hello.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
ttk.Label(frm, text="Hello World!").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=1, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to solve this by running one build step for each customer using a shell/command script and parametrize with environment variables:

`setup.py`

```py
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

sys.argv.append("bdist_msi")

program = os.environ['PROGRAM']
GUID = os.environ['GUID']

setup(
    name=f"Hello-{program}",
    version="1.0",
    executables=[Executable("hello.py")],
    options={
        "bdist_msi": {
            "initial_target_dir": f"C:\{program}",
            "upgrade_code": GUID,
        },
    },
)
```

`build.sh` / `build.cmd`

```
# Customer 1
PROGRAM = "hello"
GUID = "6ae7456f-2761-43a2-8a23-1a3dd284e947"
python setup.py

# Maybe clean build output

# Customer 2
PROGRAM = "world"
GUID = "494d5953-651d-41c5-a6ef-9156c96987a1"
python setup.py
```

With this structure you could split further and for example have one CI/CD pipeline for each customer.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. I rewrite it as PowerShell script and it works like a charm. Just one question remains - why I can't call the `setup` function more than once?

Comment: Good question, I actually don't know. As said, from a CI/CD perspective, I would in any case prefer a separate script / pipeline for each customer, sooner or later you might also have different requirements and configuration for each customer.